# Connect android phone to pc localhost not working

Tags: android

loading the localhost in mobile browser works fine, it is loading xampp at address https://192.168.100.53 but not working for android app.i have also connected my app to online database at 000webhost.com..it also worked but in case of localhost my android app is not working...
the following things are done
1.pc and android mobile is connected in same network
2.i have used the pc ip address using ipconfig in run command
3.started apache

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String myurl = "https://192.168.100.53/PhpAndroid/getTD.php";
            try {
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                try {

                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"utf-8"));
                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("profile_name","utf-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode("hello","utf-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    OS.close();
                    InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(IS,"utf-8")));
                    String respond="";
                    String row = "";
                    while((row=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                        respond =row;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    IS.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return respond;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // Log.e("error","eroo at http connection");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.e("erro","error at url");
            }
            return  null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it emulator or real device?

Comment: what exception / error code are you recieved?

Comment: Can you please post the error, exception or response code you are getting while accessing the URL

Comment: use `http` instead to `https` and if you are using `Genymotion` you have to use `10.0.0.2` ip address for localhost.

Comment: I am not using any emulator ..i just run app in android mobile phone...and when i access the localhost from android phone browser like mozilla it works file but not working when trying from running application....

Comment: Thanks M.Waqas Perves for your answer , it worked fine...